# How do i move my "Amount" prop to the right in the list component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, list, material-ui

I am having trouble moving the a prop value to the right side of the list component.

I have tried changing the Typography component and React.Fragment. And cant seem to make it work I have also tried using sx but nothing not sure if I should create a component or what type of component to place the {amount} prop .

This is my code

```
type ExploreCardsProps = {
    avatar: string
   headgear: string
   amount: number
   }


   const ListText = styled(ListItem)(()=>({
    color: "white",
   
}))


 export function ExploreCards ({avatar, headgear, amount} : ExploreCardsProps)  {
  return (
    <Grid
  container
  direction="column"
  alignItems="center"
>
<Grid item xs={3}>
    <List sx={{ width: '100%', maxWidth: 360, bgcolor: 'black'}}>
      <ListText alignItems="flex-start">
        <ListItemAvatar>
          <Avatar alt="Luis" src= {avatar} />
        </ListItemAvatar>
        <ListItemText 
          primary="Headgear"
          secondary={
            <React.Fragment>
              <Typography color="#ffffff"
                sx={{ display: 'inline'}}
                variant="body2"
                component="span"
                
              >
               {headgear}
               
              </Typography>
              {amount}
            </React.Fragment>
          }
        />
      </ListText>
      <Divider variant="inset" component="li" />
    </List>
    </Grid>
    </Grid>
  );
}
```